# The CAS server returned no response

Tags: java, single-sign-on, cas

I configure the single-sign-on on my project.
But I got a problem like below.

> org.jasig.cas.client.validation.TicketValidationException: The CAS server returned no response.

I configured the web.xml file in my project like this.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ProxyReceivingTicketValidationFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>casServerUrlPrefix</param-name>
        <param-value>https://sso.ecen.com:8443/cas</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>serverName</param-name>
        <param-value>http://localhost:8080</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Validation Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Do you know what cause it to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many days passed.
Now I know why it happened.
When I create a certification in command line.

```
keytool -genkey -alias wsria -keyalg RSA -keystore d:/keys/wsriakey
```

Then I should use the single-sign-on server domain to answer the first question.
eg.

```
sso.wsria.com
```